# Have three separate session for quiz submission in html/php

Tags: php, html

I have a quiz which has two part. The first part is the form and the second part is the confirmation of the quiz.

The Form: [The Form](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/attCertStartC.php)

I am using the POST method. So if the user submits the form and goes to the congratulation page and refreshes it, it will keep sending email out. I am trying to prevent it.

The Relevant PHP:

I am trying to change something in the following code:

```
if($fname <> "" and $lname <> "" and $ydept <> "") {
    mail ($myEmail, $mailSubject, $msgBody, $header);
    mail ($userEmail, $sentMailSubject, $sentMailBody, $sentHeader);
```

to something like this:

```
if($fname <> "" and $lname <> "" and $ydept <> "") {
    mail ($myEmail, $mailSubject, $msgBody, $header);
    mail ($userEmail, $sentMailSubject, $sentMailBody, $sentHeader);
header ("redirect me to another php page with the $fname included to be used as a variable");
}
else {
    display not complete exam page and redirect me to the form;
}
```

I would like $fname or any other variable to carry over to the congratulation.php page, so rather than the email be sent out on the same page as the congratulation page, it will be a different page so no matter how many times the user refreshes, nothing happens.

Comment: Holy Wall of Code, Batman. Try posting the relevant parts only.

Comment: SORRY wanted to post the whole script to get a better idea :)

Comment: You don't need three different sessions here, this is just a standard use of PHP sessions. Or if you don't want to use sessions, put it in a querystring variable to the congrats page. Whatever you do, make sure you properly escape whatever you write to the page or you'll be vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: I am going with Mike's answer below. Would I still be vulnerable to XSS if i use $fname = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['fName']))); code?

Talking about session, what would be the best way to go on about doing it with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent the user from refreshing the page and having an email sent again, what you need to do is redirect to another page as you have it. However in the redirected page, you will be using `GET` instead of `POST`.

```
$name = urlencode($name);
$email = urlencode($email);
header("Location: well_done_chap.php?var1=$name&var2=$email");
```

Then in `well_done_chap.php` (or whatever you call it), just do:

```
if (isset($_GET['var1']) && isset($_GET['var2'])) {
    $name = $_GET['var1'];
    $email = $_GET['var2'];

    // Do your other stuff here

} else {
    echo "Invalid access";
}
```

Comment: One issue with that is, if i load well_done_chap.php by itself it won't work. I know I can use isset to validate whether it has a var1 variable?

Comment: @SiKni8 I've updated the answer accordingly. Just check if the variables are set.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, "I would like $fname or any other variable to carry over to the congratulation.php page" I would recommend simply passing the `$_POST` array to a session variable, or, perform your calculations and save the necessary data to a separate array, and pass that array as a session variable.  Does that make sense?

Ref.  http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/7

Comment: I decided to go with Mike's solution although you is just as good. Thanks for the response :)